# How to package a webapp as a deployable war?

Tags: java, deployment, maven-2, web-applications, war

I'm new to Maven but I'm hooked on what it offers.  How do I take a webapp and have Maven package the webapp as a deployable WAR?  Additionally, can I set up Maven to automatically version the builds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [an example from the getting started guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-webapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>my-webapp</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to the project's directory and type:

mvn clean package

target/my-webapp.war is built